# Method save (Repository Spring Data) doesn't return data with ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, spring-data, jparepository

I'm trying to get data of a ManyToOne attribute after save, but I get always null to name.

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    ....
}
```

In service layer:

```
Product p = productRepository.save(product);

//print correct id
System.out.println(p.getCategory().getId());

//Always print null
System.out.println(p.getCategory().getName());
```

Any suggestion to get the name of a category in the same request?

Comment: can you update your @ManyToOne to eager and try?

Comment: I have tried this before (eager) or saveAndFlush, but the category name always return null. If I try find after save, I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try adding @JoinColum(name="a") on category where a = foreign key name in Product table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).